# Script rerun when i change selectbox in Streamlit

Tags: python-3.x, session-state, streamlit

Script rerun when I change selectbox option, I know that the streamlit code runs from tops for every action, and there is 2 solutions (caching and SessionState).

I tested caching it didn't work and for the SessionState I don't know ho to implement it.

Here’s the code

```
import streamlit as st
col1, col2, col3 = st.beta_columns(3)
if col1.button("CARTE"):
    st.write("Hello")
    sel_Map = st.selectbox("Choose Map type :", options=['Hello1', 'Hello2'], index=1)
    if sel_Map == 'ChoroplethMap':
        st.write("Hello world! 1")

    elif sel_Map == 'ChoroplethMapBox':
        st.write("Hello world! 2")

if col2.button("TABLEAU"):
    st.write("Hello world! 3")

if col3.button("SYNTHÈSE"):
    st.write("Hello world! 4")
```

Answer (score 1):

I figuredout how to use the SessionState so it turned out great here's the solution

```
import streamlit as st
from src.pages.sessionState import SessionState


session_state = SessionState.get(col1=False, col2=False, col3=False)

col1, col2, col3 = st.beta_columns(3)

col1_one = col1.button("CARTE", key="1")
col2_one = col2.button("TABLEAU", key="2")
col3_one = col3.button("SYNTHÈSE", key="3")

if col1_one or session_state.col1:
    session_state.col1 = True
    session_state.col2 = False
    session_state.col3 = False
    sel_Map = st.selectbox("Choose Map type :", options=['Hello1', 'Hello2'], index=1)
    if sel_Map == 'Hello1':
        st.write("Hello world! 1")
    elif sel_Map == 'Hello2':
        st.write("Hello world! 2")

if col2_one or session_state.col2:
    session_state.col1 = False
    session_state.col2 = True
    session_state.col3 = False
    st.write("Hello world! 3")

if col3_one or session_state.col3:
    session_state.col1 = False
    session_state.col2 = False
    session_state.col3 = True
    st.write("Hello world! 4")
```